# Importing a returned variable from a function (python 3)

Tags: python, import, primes, python-import

I am trying to write a separate module that takes in a variable from the first module (the number entered) and finds all the prime numbers up to that entered number. I understand that you cannot call a variable from within a function into another file unless it is a global variable or unless it is returned. From what I understand and I am avoiding this issue by calling a returned variable 'prime' from the function 'get_number', but I'm still getting the errors: "function 'get_number' has no 'prime' member" on the fourth line of the second file and " and "no value for argument 'prime' in function cell" on the last line of the second file. It is this error that I was trying to get around by inputting some value for prime from the first file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "beginner_python_2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from beginner_python_1 import get_number
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/beginner_python_1.py", line 5, in <module>
    prime = get_number()
NameError: name 'get_number' is not defined
```

These are my two files:

```
#a.py
import math

def main():
    number = get_number()
    is_it_prime = is_prime(number)
    print(is_it_prime)

def get_number():
    """Function to ensure user inputs a positive integer"""
    while True:
        prime = input("enter a positive integer: ")
        if prime.isdigit():
            prime = int(prime)
            return prime

def is_prime(number):
    """Function to determine if inputted integer is a prime number"""
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print("{} is not a prime number".format(number))
        return False
    if number != 2:
        for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(number))+1,2):
            if number % i == 0:
                print("{} is not a prime number".format(number))
                return False
        print("{} is a prime number".format(number))  
        return True


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

This is the second file:

```
#b.py
from a import get_number

def return_primes(prime):
    for i in range(1,a.prime+1):
    for j in range(2,i):
        if i % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print("{}".format(i),end=" ")

if __name__=="__return_primes__":
    return_primes()
```

Thank you very much for any guidance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151293/discussion-on-question-by-helloworld123-importing-a-returned-variable-from-a-fun).

Comment: And where in your source is the line `prime = get_number()`? Please show errors coherent with shown code...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want `b.py` to be something more like:

```
from a import get_number

def return_primes(limit):

    if limit > 1:
        print(2, end=" ")

    for i in range(3, limit + 1, 2):  # beyond 2, only odds are prime
        for j in range(3, int(i ** 0.5) + 1, 2): # only odds to sqrt
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:  # no break
            print(i, end=" ")

    print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    return_primes(get_number())
```

The `if __name__ == "__main__"` only tests if this file is currently being used as a library or being excuted as a program.  So it's fine to have the same test in both `a.py` and `b.py`.

**USAGE**

```
> python3 b.py
enter a positive integer: 100
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 
>
```